# Align unordered list with image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a product description with bootstrap. Now I want that the  is aligned with the image. Float left doesnt work. My image is to big so i want that is vertical aligned. here you can find a pen:

```
`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpVydZ`
```

Comment: The `<h3>Bett</h3>` is a child of the `ul`, and that is invalid code, only `li` is valid as a direct child of an `ul` ... move it before or wrap it in a `li`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should put the `ul` & `img` in a wrapper div then add `display: inline-block` + `vertical-align: middle` to each.
2. And put the image before the `ul`

Example on "Wickelkommode" :

http://codepen.io/cyril-lamotte/pen/evqKxx

Comment: hmmm.. now all my divs not in a line...
https://www.mixibaby.de/a-1003028

Comment: ok, don't put `clear: both` on your cols

Comment: OMG... thank you :D

Comment: The `<h3>Bett</h3>` is a child of the `ul`, and that is invalid code, only `li` is valid as a direct child of an `ul` ... move it before or wrap it in a `li`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img-bett col-sm-6">
                <img alt="" src="https://www.mixibaby.de/item/images/1003028/300x300/1003028-felix-grau-bett.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
            </div>

            <div class="bett-div col-sm-6">
                <h3>Bett</h3>
                <ul class="bett">   
                    <li>3-fach höhenverstellbarer Lattenrost (von 21cm auf 36cm und 52cm)</li>  
                    <li>Liegefläche: 70cm x 140cm)</li> 
                    <li>Gesamtmaße L/B/H: ca. 145cm x 77cm x 85cm</li>
                    <li>3Bodenfreiheit: ca. 8,5cm</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You are going to create two divs in the same row, the first stores the image and the second one the unordered list.

And in the css:

```
.row {
display:flex;
}
.img-bett, .bett-div {
    flex: 1;
}

ul.bett {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
}
```

The display flex allow you to change the height of the two child divs 
flex:1 make that both divs share the biggest height.
Also the position, and height of the ul makes room for him in the middle of the parent div.

Comment: at the first thank you for your answer. Now i have the problem that my UL is not aligned with my image. Link is here: https://www.mixibaby.de/a-1003028

Comment: The `<h3>Bett</h3>` is a child of the `ul`, and that is invalid code, only `li` is valid as a direct child of an `ul` ... move it before or wrap it in a `li`

Comment: It's true, I copypasted from the code in the link above, already corrected